# Handle unavailable server with vue-resource

Tags: vue.js, vue-resource

Is there a way to handle errors with `vue-resource` when a HTTP response has not been received?

For example, when the backend server is unavailable (i.e. http://localhost:30000 doesn't exist) I receive the following error in Safari:

```
[Error] Failed to load resource: Could not connect to the server. (create, line 0)
```

However the vue-resource `response` object passed to the error callback is empty (doesn't give any indication about the failure to connect to the server):

```
{ "url": "http://localhost:30000", "ok": false, "status": 0, "statusText": "", "headers": { "map": { "": [ "" ] } }, "body": null }
```

What is the best way to handle this?  Hardcoding for a `status === 0` seems like it might be overly generic?

Comment: Checking for `status === 0` seems like a good idea to me

Comment: From v1.1.0, abort/timeout request resolve to an error with a status: 0. Checking status === 0 is a good way.

Comment: Thanks folks, will go with the `status === 0` check for now.